# What’s the meaning of surah 21:22?

Tags: quran

I can’t get any good explanation for this verse, could anyone give me an explanation for this surah? as I don’t seem to understand it.

Comment: Please clarify the concrete issue and add a quote of the verse, as is written this question is not reasonably answerable.

Answer (score 1):

This concise sentence contains two arguments:

(1) The obviously simple argument is that no institution, no household, not to speak of the vast universe containing multitudes of countless distant stars, can function smoothly and properly, if it has two masters.

(2) The deeper argument is that the system of the whole universe, including that of the earth, is functioning according to a universal law. It could not work so even for a moment, if there had been no proper proportion, balance, harmony and coordination between the different powers and countless things. This is a clear proof that there is a universal and all-powerful law and system which binds and forces these powers and things to co-operate and coordinate between themselves with a perfect proportion and harmony and this could not have happened if there had been different independent rulers. The existence of such a system is itself a clear proof that there must be One All-Powerful Manager and Administrator governing and ruling the whole universe.

Comment: but wouldn't multiple gods have the same nature so want and do the same kind of things?if they are all good and benevolent,would there be opposition?

Answer (score 0):

Tafseer As-Sa'di by Shaykh Abdur Rahman al-Sa'di (teacher of Shaykh Ibn Uthaymeen) has the following to say about this verse:

What this means is that the upper and lower realms are visibly in
the most perfect shape, sound and in order, with no flaws or defects,
no resistance to the divine will and no opposition to the divine decree.
This indicates that their Controller is one, their Lord is one and their
God is one. If there were two or more controllers or lords, then their
system would falter and their pillars would collapse, because they
(those two controllers or lords) would oppose one another and strive
against one another. If one of them wanted one thing, the other would
want the opposite. Therefore it is impossible for two wills to coexist,
and if the will of one was done but not the other, this would indicate
that the other was helpless and incapable, but it would be impossible
for both to agree on one thing in all matters.

Therefore it must be the case that the Controller Whose will alone
is done, without any resistance or opposition, is Allah, the One, the
Subduer. Hence Allah refers to this argument when He says:
«(Allah has never begotten a son, nor is there any god besides Him.
[In that case,] each god would have taken full control of what he had
created, and each would have rushed to gain supremacy over the
others. Glory be to Allah and [exalted be He] far above what they
ascribe [to Him].]? (al-Mu 'minoon 23: 91)

- and:

^Say [O Muhammad]: If there were [other] gods with Him, as
they say, they would surely have sought a way to the Lord o f the
Throne.18 Glory be to Him, and exalted be He far above what they
say!]? (al-lsra 17: 42-43)

Hence Allah says here: ((Glory be to Allah)? that is, exalted be He
above all shortcomings, for He alone is perfect
^Lord of the Throne)? which is above all creation, and is the vastest
and greatest of all created things. If He is Lord of the Throne, it is
even more appropriate for Him to be Lord o f whatever is beneath it.
((and [exalted be He] far above what they ascribe [to Him])? that is,
what the disbelievers ascribe to Him, of having begotten offspring or
taken a wife, or having a partner in any way whatsoever.

Source: https://www.kalamullah.com/Books/Tafseer-As-Sadi-Volume-6-Juz-16-18.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Al-Anbiya 21:22 Had there been within the heavens and earth gods besides Allah, they both would have been ruined. So exalted is Allah, Lord of the Throne, above what they describe.

In short, Allah is talking about His Oneness; His power in this ayah. That it's not possible for Him to have a partner otherwise the world would be in calamity; ruins, due to both wanting opposite things from each other or wanting things to be created differently to one another. Yet look at the perfection of the creations.  Nothing can possibly function so perfectly if it has two or more masters. Not to speak of the vast universe containing multitudes of countless distant stars.